# How to Subtract column from another in dataset

Tags: dataset, column

I want to subtract the "assigned_ts" values from the "closed_ts" column and paste the results in seconds into the column with the "difference_ts" header.
[image: Dataset table]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
ds = {
   <|"assigned_ts" -> "2017-04-20 12:09:39", "closed_ts" -> "2017-04-20 13:13:01"|>,
   <|"assigned_ts" -> "2017-04-20 12:10:30", "closed_ts" -> "2017-04-20 12:28:29"|>} // Dataset

ds[All, <|#, 
   "difference_ts" -> DateDifference[DateObject[#"assigned_ts"], DateObject[#"closed_ts"], "Second"]|> &]
```

[image]